# NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm able to signup with Devise just fine, but sign in isn't working.

Here's my current setup:

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }

  root "profiles#index"
    resources :profiles


  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end


# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

end


#sessions/new.html.erb

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>


# sessions_controller.rb
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

The error message is this:
[image]

Update:
Might have been my application_controller:
It was

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        redirect_to edit_user_profile_path unless current_user.profile.completed_profile?
    end
end
```

and is now:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
end
```